# Windows VM not booting with virt-manager on existing ssd but working with qemu command

Tags: windows, qemu, kvm

I am trying to boot up my Windows install, which is installed on a seprate sata ssd and is bootable. I tried pretty much everything to get it to boot with virt-manager but its always just showing the UEFI screen. It is working with a quemu command and baremetal though.

Anyone got any hints as to why its not working?

Working:

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 --enable-kvm -cpu host -smp 8 -m 8192 -drive format=raw,file=/dev/sda
```

Not working xml:

```
<disk type="block" device="disk">
  <driver name="qemu" type="raw" cache="none" io="native" discard="unmap"/>
  <source dev="/dev/sda" index="1"/>
  <backingStore/>
  <target dev="sda" bus="sata"/>
  <alias name="sata0-0-0"/>
  <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="0"/>
</disk>
```